# loop through checkboxes in Silverlight (VB)

Tags: vb.net, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a series of checkboxes that I want to allow the user to check multiple items. I need to identify which boxes are checked (In a loop I assume) and return the content of the CHECKED check boxes and then query that content in order to display any item that contains those attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are creating the checkboxes at runtime, I would not *loop* through them, just ask for the value of each one. (Important that you NAME your checkboxes in your XAML so you can access them by name)

```
If CheckBox1.IsChecked Then
  '... What to do when checked
Else
  '... What to do when not checked
End If
If CheckBox2.IsChecked Then
  '... What to do when checked
Else
  '... What to do when not checked
End If
If CheckBox3.IsChecked Then
  '... What to do when checked
Else
  '... What to do when not checked
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Steve - I was doing that exact formula, but I wanted to see the CONTENT value of the checkboxes in a textbox and it would only return the last checkbox's value. I was using = instead of +=, once I changed that I was able to see all the values.

Comment: Curious - using the ELSE to tell it what NOT to do. If I want that to literally be NOTHING, what would I put in that statement?

Comment: Not sure _what_ you want to be `nothing`? If you have a variable, you can do this `x = nothing`, if you're saying you dont want the else, then exclude the `else`.